# Output impedance of differential amplifier

Tags: bjt

How do I calculate output impedance of the following differential amplifier?

Input are at the base of two BJTs.

I know that it's Rc || resistance looking into the collector of Q2, but how to find that value?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi1e3O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the internet: -

[image]

It shows collector current versus CE voltage for several base currents. The graphs indicate the natural slope resistance of the collector. For instance, when \$I_B\$ = 40 uA, I estimate that a collector current range of 8 mA to 8.75 mA corresponds to a CE range of 1V to 8V.

This means the slope resistance is \$\dfrac{7\space V}{0.75\space mA}\$ = 9333 ohms.

This slope resistance, in parallel with the collector resistor (Rc) dictates what the output resistance of the amplifier is. Re will have a small effect on this of course.

If you are serious about finding out, the next step would be simulation.

Comment: Why does Re has small effect on Rout?

Comment: Because a transistor collector has slope it has internal resistance (as per the 9333 ohms above) and this HAS to be in series with Re therefore Re increases the output resistance.

Comment: Is the output resistance equals to \$R_c // R_{\text{LOAD}}\$? If so, how does the slope resistance dictate on the output resistance?

Comment: @hkBattousai Yes it does. Your 2nd question is answered implicitly from your correct assertion (unless you mean something else)?